# why nginx proxy_pass to sub directory is not working?

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxypass

I am trying to do a proxy_pass to a subdirectory `http://ms.server.com:8085/ms`. So whenever anyone hit on `http://ms.example.com' it should be redirected to`http://ms.example.com/ms`. I am trying to do that through below configuration

```
upstream example {
  server ms.server.com:8085;
}

server {
    server_name     ms.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://example/ms;
    }
  }
```

Now I am redirecting to "Nginx Test page".

Answer (score -1):

`proxy_pass` is used to inform Nginx where to send proxied requests at a host level, and does not account for the URI.

What you want to use instead is a `return` statement, like so:

```
upstream example {
   server ms.server.com:8085;
}

server {
    server_name     ms.example.com;

    location = / {
        return 301 http://ms.example.com/ms;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://example;
    }
}
```

This will redirect requests to the root URL of the `server_name` `http://ms.example.com` using a `301` redirect, and all other traffic will be passed through to the defined upstream.